# How to install the scm perforce provider for SonarQube 5.3?

Tags: sonarqube, perforce, sonarqube5.3

I want to use perforce as SonarQube 5.3 scm provider, but it failed with this error message:

```
ERROR: SCM provider was set to "perforce" but no SCM provider found for this key.
Supported SCM providers are svn,git
```

I want to install perforce plugin in SonarQube update center, but it said:

```
Error while downloading plugin 'scmperforce' with version '1.4'.
No compatible plugin found.
```

And I can't find any available scm perforce plugins on the SonarQube website.

How to use perforce with SonarQube 5.3?

Answer (score 2):

The current version of SonarQube is 6.4 and the current LTS is 5.6.6. Plugin versions only compatible with versions lower than those have been purged from the Update Center.

There is, however, a version of the Perforce plugin that's compatible with 5.6.6.